# Python sum(generator): calling an external function

Tags: python, generator

take the code:

```
SUM = sum(x() for x in xs)
```

I am writing some code that is in need of calling another function before each x() such that x() will compute the right value

is the only way to do this like so?

```
for x in xs: x.pre()

SUM = sum(x() for x in xs)
```

or

```
SUM = 0
for x in xs:
    x.pre()
    SUM += x()
```

incorporating x.pre into x is obviously possible but would make the real code exceptionally ugly and hard to read. is there some way of using generator expressions I am unaware of that would allow what I am trying to achieve?

eg:

```
SUM = sum(x(), x.pre() for x in xs)
```

thats obviously just an non-summable tuple generator

Comment: Another particularly ugly way would be `sum((x.pre(), x())[1] for x in xs)`...

Comment: The explicit for loop that doesn't use the `sum()` built-in is a very good solution.  It's very readable, and I can't see any downsides.

Comment: @Sven: normally I'd say it has the (slight) downside that it uses a mutable variable, but since all these `x` objects are mutable anyway that's a drop in the ocean of reasoning about state required to read this code :-)

Comment: the initialisation `SUM=0` is actually a very complex call I am trying to avoid, huge syntactic mess

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the `for`-loop you already presented.

There are ways to do what you want in other ways. For example you could use `functools.reduce` with a customized function here instead of `sum` :

```
def pre_then_add(accumulated, new_one):
    new_one.pre()  # do some stuff so we get the right value
    return accumulated + new_one() # add the value to the accumulated sum
```

and then it's just a matter of calling `reduce`:

```
import functools

functools.reduce(pre_then_add, xs, 0)
```

Note that this requires to give a "base value" otherwise the function is too simple but also that `reduce` with a customized function is not necessarily the most efficient or elegant way.

As pointed in the comments (thanks to @SteveJessop) another possibility using `sum` would be:

```
def pre_then_call(x): 
    x.pre(); 
    return x()

sum(pre_then_call(x) for x in xs)
```

---

But just to repeat it: I would use the explicit loop. Those are far easier to understand in terms of what you are doing and why.

Comment: Similarly you could do `def pre_then_call(x): x.pre(); return x()`, then `sum(pre_then_call(x) for x in xs)`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I knew I shouldn't have included the example. I have only included it to show how such an approach is less readable (in my opinion) and only "outsources" what is actually done. At least as long as it's not a builtin - where actual performance reasons might justify such a ``sum``.